# Geojson file is not imported correctly if there is geometry in the properties

Tags: java, geojson, geotools

Input file:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "name": "smth_name",
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326"
    }
  },
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "testid": 2,
        "other_geom": {
          "type": "Point", "coordinates": [44.3, 33.3] 
        }
      },      
      "geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon",
          "coordinates":[[[[33.5461,33.44],[33.441,33.447],[33.6718,33.448],[33.0188,33.441],[33.5461,33.44]]]]}
    }
  ]
}
```

As a result, I get an object with a point geometry (44.3, 33.3), rather than a polygonal one.

How to ignore geometry in feature properties or other complex fields?

Used geotools gt-geojsondatastore 19.0 version.

```
GeoJSONDataStore geoJSONDataStore = new GeoJSONDataStore(jsonFile.toURI().toURL());
SimpleFeature simpleFeature = geoJSONDataStore.getFeatures()...next();
Point geometry = simpleFeature.getDefaultGeometry()
```

Answer (score 1):

In your builder, you have set your default geometry to point to `other_geom`, ie. of type `Point` object. Set it to be of type `MultiPolygon` ( `geometry` ).

```
SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
builder.setDefaultGeometry("geometry");
```

and in your extraction

```
MultiPolygon geometry = simpleFeature.getDefaultGeometry();
```

Comment: The input file is generated on outside, I can not affect its structure.